# Add space between point of the chart and of the border chart in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

My chart:

```
<div style={{height: '100%', marginTop:'-20px'}}>
   <Line data={data} options={options} />
</div>
```

and options for chart:

```
const options = {
  scales:{
    yAxes:[{
      scaleLabel:{
        display: true,
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

[image]

Now I have this situation, the second point stops at the upper border. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define [`ticks.max`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#step-size) on the y-axis as follow:

```
yAxes:[{
  ticks:{
    min: 0,
    max: 100 // or whatever value that suits you
  }
}]
```